# Team Foundation Server 2012 Express Installation Fails on Web Server

Tags: visual-studio

I am having problems configuring TFS Express. It seems like it is having trouble with C:\Windows\Temp folder. Although, I am running the install on Administrator

[Error  @17:38:53.863] 
Exception Message: TF255077: The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path: C:\Windows\temp. (type ConfigurationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureSetAcls.Run(ActivityContext context)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.AddAccessToDirectory(String groupName, FileSystemRights rights, String path, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FileSystemHandler.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, ITFLogger logger)

[Info   @17:38:53.863] Node returned: Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you are running Avast antivirus. To workaround the issue, you can disable Avast self-defense module.